# tslearn package not seeing numpy installation python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jenkins, pip

I'm trying to install python requirements in jenkins through

```
pip install requirements.cfg
```

For now i have 3 packages in requirements file: numpy, pandas and tslearn. Numpy and pandas are installed correctly and when trying to install tslearn it failes because 'numpy is not installed'. I'm installing in conda virtual environment.

Here is a jenkins job output:

```
Collecting numpy==1.14.3 (from -r pip_requirements.cfg (line 1))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/09/6f302aba4a08ffcd34b20a6ee94f34a76207105f59acd83462b81469c06e/numpy-1.14.3-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pandas==0.19.2 (from -r pip_requirements.cfg (line 2))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/c9/0197da1728e813d37b8b38f795aac95ea0c334b75b365078b2b8476dcd11/pandas-0.19.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tslearn>=0.1.9 (from -r pip_requirements.cfg (line 3))
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/9e/4315deb6e42ed0fc8dc5e233c90b6b843199686119d5429b835a4ca25e41/tslearn-0.1.19.2.tar.gz (584kB)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\econib.ci\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-s3wdsvej\tslearn\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: i changed pip to pip3 and now when trying to install tslearn the output says 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython''

Answer (score 2):

This might solve your problem as it always helps me with new packages.

1. Update the numpy package and others required. (version)
2. Install visual studio c++ modules. (recommended)
3. Try installing from the source package (which you can learn online) rather than downloading and installing using pip or pip3.
4. Read the documentation of the package again.